# Recognize active backend login

Tags: php, session, yii2

I set diffrent identityCookie name and session name for frontend section and backend section.

My question is how to recognize active backend login in frontend section? I have two separately login form each for my sections.

I used abhi1693/yii2-user from github and advnaced yii2 template.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific here, @kajti. This question is really unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write you own code. If frontend & backend located on one domain you can store user id in cookies. Frontend will know that if a cookie with a specific name is exists that user have active backend login.

[Yii2 have useful manual about cookie](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/cookies.md). Try write after backend login. Of course you should [protect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html#hashData()-detail), and validate cookie value before read, because client can replace it.

```
$cookie = new Cookie([
    'name' => 'isBackendLogin',
    'value' => \Yii::$app->security->hashData(Yii::$app->user->id, 'salt'),
    'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
]);
\Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
```

in Frontend you can check this cookie:

```
$isBackendLoginHash = \Yii::$app->request->cookies->getValue('isBackendLogin'); 
$isBackendLogin = \Yii::$app->security->validateData($isBackendLoginHash, 'salt');
```

Comment: ok, it nice idea but a little dangerous. Cookie is easy to craft